# Pygame - Crashing when trying to shoot

Tags: python, pygame, atom-editor

I am trying to learn Python and wanted to practice with Pygame. I am currently using Python 3.6.5 and running the code in Atom 1.27.2 and installed the atom-runner package.  I have been following the KidsCanCode [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=33g62PpFwsE&t=363s) for Pygame on Youtube.

I wanted to change the code around so I am not just copying the tutorial.  At the moment everything works until I try to spawn a bullet from my ship.  The bullet is supposed to go from the left to right, spawning from the ship on the left side of the screen.  Once the program loads all ships are moving as expected with collisions working, however when I hit space bar the game crashes with the following error:

```
TypeError: add() argument after * must be an iterable, not int
```

I thought it has to do with my player.shoot function but if I remove the function and try to spawn the bullet under...

```
if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
```

It still doesn't work.

I have the code similar to the code on the video but it still doesn't seem to work. Maybe it has to do with my .rect positions for the bullet, but at this point I am not really sure.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pygame as pg
import random
import os

WIDTH = 1200
HEIGHT = 700
FPS = 60

#-----define colors-----
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

# set up assets folders
game_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
img_folder = os.path.join(game_folder, 'graphics')

pg.init()
pg.mixer.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pg.display.set_caption('First Game')
clock = pg.time.Clock()

# ------Load graphics-------------
player_img = pg.image.load(os.path.join(img_folder, 'blueship1.png')).convert()
enemy1_img = pg.image.load(os.path.join(img_folder, 'enemy1.png')).convert()


# ------------ Sprite for the player---------
class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.transform.scale(player_img, (80, 60))
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.midleft =  (0, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        self.speedy = 0
        keystate = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pg.K_UP]:
            self.speedy = -5
        if keystate[pg.K_DOWN]:
            self.speedy = 5
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.bottom > HEIGHT:
            self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT
        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.rect.top = 0

    def shoot(self):
        laser = laser1(self.rect.midright, self.rect.centery)
        all_sprites.add(laser)
        lasers.add(laser)

class Enemy1(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.transform.scale(enemy1_img, (80, 60))
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(HEIGHT - self.rect.height)
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH + 40, WIDTH + 100)
        self.speedx = random.randrange(-8, -1)
    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(HEIGHT - self.rect.height)
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH + 40, WIDTH + 100)
            self.speedx = random.randrange(-8, -1)

class laser1(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __int__(self, x, y):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((10, 5))
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centery = y
        self.rect.left = x
        self.speedx = 15

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        #kill at right side of screen
        if self.rect.left > WIDTH:
            self.kill()

#  ---initializes pygame and creates window---
all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
mobs = pg.sprite.Group()
lasers = pg.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)
for i in range(8):
    m = Enemy1()
    all_sprites.add(m)
    mobs.add(m)

# --------------Game loop-----------------

running = True
while running:
    # ------keep loop running at right speed-----
    clock.tick(FPS)
    # ------Process input (events)--------
    for event in pg.event.get():
        #check for closing window
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                player.shoot()

    # ----------Update---------------
    all_sprites.update()

    # --------------Checking for Collisions----------------
    hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(player, mobs, False)
    if hits:
        running = False

    # ---------Draw / render----------------
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    # flip after drawing
    pg.display.flip()
```

Comment: What's the full error?

Comment: It's a typo, `laser1.__int__` instead of `laser1.__init__`. Typos are off-topic here so I vote to close the question. Also, you probably want to pass `self.rect.right` when you instantiate the laser1 instead of `midright`: `laser1(self.rect.right, self.rect.centery)`.

Comment: Awesome, that was it, not sure how I overlooked that... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is caused by a typo. The name of the constructor is `__init__` rather than `__int__`

<s>`def __int__(self, x, y):`</s>

```py
def __init__(self, x, y):
```